# Feign Call from asynchronous method

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I have Spring event Publisher and listener where the requirement is as below:

1. Trigger the event from some method.
2. Listen the event from listener class
3. As soon as event is listened Call another micro-service

So currently i am using [openfeign](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/single/spring-cloud-openfeign.html) to call another micro-service.

This call works fine when the listener method runs Synchronously and it fails when listener method is marked as @Async.

Below is the sample code:
**Fiegn Interface configuration:**

```
@AuthorizedFeignClient(name = "another-microservice")
public interface CustomFeignInterface {
    @PostMapping("api/call")
    public ResponseEntity<String> callMethod(@RequestBody Foo foo);
}
```

**Spring event Listener:**

```
@Component
public class FooEventListener {

    @Autowired
    private CustomFeignInterface customFeignInt;

    @Async
    @EventListener
    public void handleCustomEvent(Foo foo) {
        try {
            ResponseEntity<String> res = customFeignInt.callMethod(foo);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

As per above code Call to another micro-service works perfect when i remove @Async but fails when i add @Async to `FooEventListener.handleCustomEvent(..)` method.

Somewhere i found that Feign does not support Async calls:
 https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/issues/361

But still i need async behavior how can i achieve that?

Comment: I don't see how the Feign issue you linked to relates to `@Async`. How does it fail? As Async executes on another thread, are you sure you propagated thread local variables that could be required to make the call?

Comment: Can you provide more information about what "fails" with the @Async annotation?